# AVPlayer Advance to Next Stream URL when Finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I have a table view with tracks from Soundcloud. When a row is selected, the track streams. How can I get it to automatically advance to the track in the next cell when a track finishes?

Here is some of the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }

    if (cell)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

        if (indexPath.row == selectedRow)
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio_wave"];
            UIImage *musicOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio_wave"];
            UIImage *musicTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio_wave_2"];
            UIImage *musicThree = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio_wave_3"];
            UIImage *musicFour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audio_wave_4"];

            NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:musicOne, musicTwo, musicThree, musicFour, nil];

            cell.imageView.animationImages = imagesArray;
            cell.imageView.animationDuration = 0.62;
            cell.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
            [cell.imageView startAnimating];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = nil;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *streamingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.json?client_id=fc886d005e29ba78f046e5474e3fdefb", [streamURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSURL *streamingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:streamingString];
    selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamingURL];
    [player play];
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` observer to trigger the changes, ex:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *streamingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.json?client_id=fc886d005e29ba78f046e5474e3fdefb", [streamURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSURL *streamingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:streamingString];
    selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];

    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamingURL];
    [player play];
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                      selector:@selector(goToNextTrack)
                      name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                      object:nil];
}

- (void)goToNextTrack {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                      name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                      object:nil];
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRow+1 inSection:0]];
}
```

Comment: I've added selectedRow++;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; to the end of the code you suggested and the image view moves to the next cell when a track finishes but the next track doesn't play.

Comment: @user2029585 Why are you adding selectedRow++ when I've already added 1 to selectedRow in the cellForRowAtIndexPath call during goToNextTrack? As for the other part of your issue, perhaps you also need to nil out the player object before reinitializing it, i.e. player = nil

Comment: @user2029585 I'm still confused as to what your current code looks like.  Something's wrong if you had to add `selectedRow ++`  `[self.tableView reloadData];`. It seems as if you're not actually calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again

Comment: @user2029585 Actually, my mistake, I meant to call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` not `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in `goToNextTrack`. Updated. And remove the extra code you added.

Comment: @user2029585 And never update your question to include the answer code like you just did because then the question and answer will no longer make sense.